# How to validate a field value in a form doesn't exit in a database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a human resourses database where I have a person table with a SSN field. Since there will be various types of people categorized by a person type field not all of them will be required to give an ssn.  Because of this, I cannot key on this field. So I want to use the form validation jquery plugin to validate it is a unique ssn.

I have worked with the validation plugin but not like this.  This is my idea.
On submit I will grab the value of the ssn and using ajax post it to a php file which will check its format and then do a query that will be basically

```
"select ssn from person table where ssn = ".$ssn;
```

I will then use  sqlsrv_has_rows to see if I get a result.  If I will echo back something 1 if there is an already exist record with that ssn. 
This is where I get stuck at.  What would be the rule.  It cannot be required:ssn because it is not required but it must be something that says this is not valid because I have returned this 1 from the ajax function.  I hope this makes sense.  Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Having multiple `null` values in a column with a unique key on it, should not cause any problems at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery Validation Plugin remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method). Your PHP script needs to return `true` for a valid SSN, for an invalid SSN return `false` or `null` (each response JSON encoded). In the PHP script, the SSN to check will be available via `$_GET['ssnInputFieldName']` (if you don't configure another HTTP method). To check if the SSN already exists you can also use the SQL `COUNT()` function:

```
select count(*) from table person where ssn = ?
```